# Strong name signatures are invalid for this assembly Antlr4.Runtime.Standard.dll

Tags: c#, antlr4

I use Antlr4.Runtime.Standard.dll 4.7.2 in my project. But when I built mode release and install in another PC which using the Symantect Endpoint Protection, it error.

> Strong name signatures are invalid for this assembly Antlr4.Runtime.Standard.dll.

I try signing the ClickOne manifest.

Can you help me, please? Thank you

Comment: Try to turn Shadowcopy off.